# Why does the value changes after set_index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('node.txt', header=None)
df = df.sort_values([1, 2, 3], ascending=[False, False, True])
dff2 = df
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
dff = df
```

I tried to sort the columns in order of column number and checked the dataframe `dff2` and `dff`.
However, after the `reset_index` method the values in column are little different.

dff2

[image]

dff

[image]

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example as text, not images? In the meantime, try rerunning your code, but with `dff2 = df.copy()` instead of `dff2 = df`.

Comment: It works. thank you! Is there a reason why you recommended .copy() method?

Comment: From the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html): Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.